# How can I enable in-page navigation in a Quasar 2 / Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'm in the process of porting my app across to Quasar 2 / Vue 3, and every time I navigate to a new menu item, the DevTools network panel is cleared, and a new collection of files is requested from the server. This results in the browser page being cleared, the menu has to redraw (and expand to show the selected item) and the QPageContainer content is then reloaded.

In my Quasar 1 / Vue 2 app, I could navigate through the different menu items and see in DevTools that the page itself wasn't being refreshed. I was able to see new modules being downloaded in the network tab and simply being added to the collection of downloaded files. The menu stayed put (without being redrawn), and the content corresponding to the menu item was loaded into the QPageContainer.

The new version makes for a clunky feel, and I much prefer the smoothness of the original code.

I was using vite in the new version, but just spent the afternoon switching over to webpack with no difference after the switch. Chunking components in webpack doesn't seem to make a difference.

Hopefully I'm missing something simple ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, missing something simple. I'd introduced a new component for handling the menu items. It had an `<a href="new-page">New page</a>` instead of a `<router-link to="new-page">New page</router-link>`. The `router-link` component does the navigation I want.

Sheesh.